# Check a field on related Account Object

Tags: process-builder

I am using Professional Edition and in my lead object Status field there are 4 values:

- SQL
- Meeting Happened
- SQL Later
- SQL-to-Oppty

Now what I want is that  whenever a lead status is changed among these four values then the Active lead should be check marked on Account Object.

Comment: Is there any criteria that you would like to have to uncheck this checkbox? I only ask because I dont understand what use case this has. Because once a change is made to that field, this box will be checked forever.

Comment: @cmmoutes13 Thanks for the response. Yes criteria should be if  the lead status should be changed from these 4 fields then the active lead should be unchecked from Account Object.

Comment: Oh alright, so there are extra option on this pick list then the four you listed?

Comment: Yes , but the automation will fired only on these four.